# How to make a wordpress blog in two different languages?

Tags: multi-language

I have a news blog and i am posting news in English. Now I want to make another section where I want to display news only in Urdu language.
I also want to keep both languages separate that when I am on English news, no Urdu news should be shown anywhere and when I click on Urdu news page, no post from English section should be shown.

Should I use two different wordpress installations on same domain to achieve this thing ?

For example, my website is www.mywebsite.com and have another wordpress installation www.mywebsite.com/urdu-news/ and I make a custom link in www.mywebsite.com for www.mywebsite.com/urdu-news/.
If yes, what about google ads I am gonna show on my pages. Will these ads are considered as in one website or I need to register www.mywebsite.com/urdu-news/ with google adsense separately ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't create two wordpress installation because it is wasting resources. I think you should use wordpress translation plugins. Just google it. As for me, I use [polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/). You could use **News** with category based or you could also create custom template and make query for that.